# Laravel Homestead: Base table not found

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, vagrant, lumen

I am experimenting with Laravel's Homestead today and managed to overcome some issues with vagrant and virtualbox.

However, running `php artisan migrate` I am getting this message, which indicates that it expects a db in place:

`[PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.authentication' doesn't exist`

Any ideas or recommendations about the next step?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to declare the name of the table in your model? Something like `protected $table = 'authentication';`.